# Binding entity property to combobox not working as expected

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, bindingsource

I have an entity, eg:

```
public class Entity
{
    public Enum1 FirstEnum { get; set; }
    public Enum2 SecondEnum { get; set; }
}
```

This entity is bound to a `BindingSource` which in turn binds controls on the form; eg.:

```
this.cboSecondEnum.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("SelectedValue", this.bindingSource, "SecondEnum", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, Enum2.Default));
```

In order to change some details when the user changes the value in the `ComboBox` I have:

```
private void cboSecondEnum_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cboSecondEnum.SelectedValue == null)
        return;

    var item = (Enum2)cboSecondEnum.SelectedValue;

    //Do something...
}
```

So far, the above works fine when the user is entering data in the form, and the entity is saved correctly in the db.

However, the problem is when loading back that same entity. After setting the binding source as follows:

```
this.bindingSource.DataSource = myEntity;
```

The `SelectedValueChange` event is raised at some point during the binding of the controls and the `SelectedValue` is still not set based on the entity's property. This happens only to `ComboBox` controls. Other data-bound controls work as expected.

When the user changes some other control (and the data source is updated automatically through the binding source), all controls are refreshed and it is at this point that the `ComboBox` values reflect the actual values of the entity's properties.

The expected behavior is that `ComboBox` value is set correctly when setting the `DataSource` property of the `BindingSource`.

Am I missing something here? Is this an issue with databinding in WinForms projects?

Comment: If your binding is working correctly then you shouldn't need the SelectedValueChanged event! Making the code you've supplied up to the `// Do Something` irrelevant. If binding has been successful then your `myEntity.SecondEnum` instance should already contain the selected value. Are you populating the combobox before you add the binding to myEntity? Something else you should do is implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your Entity class so that your binding source is notified when the properties have updated.

Comment: You can try to use `SelectionChangeCommitted` event instead of `SelectedValueChanged`.